# Error 405 using axios request in react native iOS app

Tags: ios, react-native, axios

I have react native application. my API not on localhost
when I was using it for android everything was fine.
but for iOS every time the app makes a post request I got 405 error response

My API uses HTTP.

I searched for how to solve it and I found that this error comes from option request.
I added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *`

to my API but still, have the same problem

Comment: did u find any solution ?